# How can I add "mentions" to forum post content in php?

Tags: php, regex

I am building a forum from scratch with procedural PHP (and AJAX). When a user mentions another user "`@anotheruser`", I am wanting to replace that with a link to the other user's account  `<a href="#">@anotheruser</a>`.

I have tried the following:

```
preg_match_all('/\s\@\w+/',$content,$matches);

foreach($matches[0] as $match){
    $contentWithMentions = preg_replace("/$match/", '<a href="user.php?user=#">'.$match.'</a>', $content);
}

echo $contentWithMentions;
```

However, this approach is only applying the link to the last mention in the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you're always replacing the reference in the original content, not the content that has been updated with the previous replacements. Try this instead:

```
$contentWithMentions = $content;
preg_match_all('/\s\@\w+/',$content,$matches);
foreach ($matches[0] as $match) {
    $contentWithMentions = str_replace("/$match/", '<a href="user.php?user=#">'.$match.'</a>', $contentWithMentions);
}
echo $contentWithMentions;
```

Note that you don't actually need `preg_replace` to do the replacements as you are no longer using a regex, so you can just use `str_replace`.

Note that if you don't actually need the match results you can simplify this by just doing the `preg_replace` directly and skipping the `preg_match` step:

```
$content = "And so @Nick said to @Joe, hello!";
$contentWithMentions = preg_replace('/\s\@\w+/', '<a href="user.php?user=#">'."$0".'</a>', $content);
echo $contentWithMentions;
```

Output

```
And so<a href="user.php?user=#"> @Nick</a> said to<a href="user.php?user=#"> @Joe</a>, hello!
```

[Demo of both solutions on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/A7eJ7)

Comment: @Hayden I've edited my post with some simpler code if you don't want to collect all the matches.

Answer (score 2):

Your approach is losing the whitespace before the link. There's no need for the loop at all:

```
$content = 'here is a @user and here is @anotheruser and a @third';
$new_content = preg_replace('/(\s+)(@\w+)/', '$1<a href="user.php?user=#">$2</a>', $content);
echo $new_content;
```

Output:

```
here is a <a href="user.php?user=#">@user</a> and here is <a href="user.php?user=#">@anotheruser</a> and a <a href="user.php?user=#">@third</a>
```